# How to use Bootstrap popovers in mvc validation message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use Bootstrap popovers for mvc validation message

My code is:

```
<form id="form-signup_v1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label>Amount</label>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, null, new { data_toggle = "popover", data_content = "Content of Popover like a simple form etc." ,data_placement= "left" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <input value="Button" type="submit">
</form>
```

Java script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();

});
</script>
```

Now I am getting error message like below

[image]

but I need error message in poppover

Update 1

HTML code using developer tool:

```
<form id="form-signup_v1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <textarea cols="20" 
                      data-val="true" 
                      data-val-required="The Amount old field is required." 
                      id="FirstName" 
                      name="FirstName" 
                      rows="2">
            </textarea>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" 
                  data-content="Content of Popover like a simple form etc." 
                  data-placement="left" 
                  data-toggle="popover" 
                  data-valmsg-for="FirstName" 
                  data-valmsg-replace="true">
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input value="Button" type="submit">
</form>
```

where I made error

thanks .....

Comment: What does the HTML for the validation message look like?

Comment: @ JB06 sorry i dnt get you...what your trying to say

Comment: If you view the source HTML for the element you are trying to make a popover, by using the developer tools in your browser, what does it look like?

Comment: @ JB06 i have update my Qus with Html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a bootply example, with your Razor converted to HTML as if the field was invalid. http://www.bootply.com/HtIaotAZfv

The relevant javascript is this:

```
    $("[data-toggle='popover']").each(function() 
      { 
        $(this).popover( {
          title: $(this).data("valMsgFor"),
          content: $(this).text()
        })
        .html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign text-danger'></i>");
      }
   );
```

This relies on the HTML helper putting the data-val-msg-for attribute on the span tag to get the title for the popover, and then defines the content of the popover.

I don't know what you had in mind to style this, because you still have the full text of the validation message present. You could attach a call to jQuery's .text() or .html() at the end of the .popover() and insert a glyphicon, for example, though, as I did above.

Comment: Actually, if you're using the glyphicon method, you'll want to use a better selector, like `.field-validation-error[data-toggle='popover']` or the glyphicons will show up even before the field is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for repose. i have tried your code but its showing normal error message after clicking button....

Comment: Create your own bootply with the HTML / javascript from your view so we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Bootstrap popover documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), the popover data- attributes need to be on the element that you want the popover on. Take all the data- attributes from the generated validation span and place them on your textarea and see if that works.

Copying data- attributes is not the best way to do that by far, but it will get you headed in the right direction.